# Why is it hard to ferment fennel?

Tags: fermentation

Fennel seemed like a natural for lacto-fermentation.

There are many recipes with fennel as an ingredient (especially in cabbage kraut), but no one seemed to talk about just fermenting up a big ol' batch of fennel.

So I gave it a spin using my standard brine: 3T kosher salt per quart plus bay leaves, peppercorns, and corriander. I ran one batch with two mason jars of fennel, and a second batch with three.

Of the five jars, three turned out delicious but took a **weirdly** long time. I left the other two jars running for 5-6 weeks but they didn't show the active bubbling I expect and they never really came together. They were somewhat tart, but their pH was up around 5 instead of down in the 4's where it should have been.

Is there some reason fennel doesn't want to ferment?

Comment: Hmm, I wonder how much in the way of carbohydrates there are in fennel compared to cabbage or whatnot.

Comment: I saw this, maybe you can give it a try :)
http://ediblehouston.ediblecommunities.com/recipes/fermented-fennel-relish

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After dumping out a couple of jars of failed not-quite-fermented fennel I wondered, "Could fennel have antimicrobial properties?"

**<< facepalm >>**

Why, yes. Yes it could:

- [An article on PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20136455)
- [Another on PubMed](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15612826)
- [One on Science Direct](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S092666901200564X)
- [One on Research Gate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/230025639_Antioxidant_and_antimicrobial_activities_of_essential_oil_and_extracts_of_fennel_Foeniculum_vulgare_Mill_seeds_from_Pakistan)

Granted, these are about the essential oil and not the whole plant. So I can't be sure this is the problem, but it seems very likely.

Maybe a little fennel mixed in with something else won't muck up the fermentation process, whereas a whole jar of fennel can.

And though it's hard to know, I suppose there could be a safety concern. Lacto fermentation protects us through (1) salt, (2) oxygen depletion, and (3) acid production. Based on what I saw with the failed batches, (2) and (3) may have been below normal. If salt-tolerant critters were to survive... that could be bad.

Comment: I wonder if that can even create a risk of something unexpected/unwanted (and less affected by the antimicrobial oil) taking over the fermentation?

Comment: @rackandboneman That seems possible. Lacto fermentation protects through salt, oxygen depletion, and acid production. With the latter two being reduced, maybe some salt-tolerant critters could survive. I sampled the failed batches several times, but maybe I just got lucky. I'll add a little note about that in the answer.